# HTML - формат номера для ссылки tel

Tags: html, ссылки

Везде нахожу информацию, что формат номера телефона для ссылки tel такой: цифры и плюс (если нужен), без пробелов, тире и скобок. Но если в ссылку вставить такой номер: `+7 (800) 000-00-00` - она остается рабочей и с моего телефона обрабатывается правильно (Android 7.1.2 - chrome 74). Получается, что номер телефона может быть в любом формате? Или от этого начинаются проблемы (не все телефоны открывают и т.д.)

Comment: В некоторых старых телефонов и старых версии android не было преобразования. Поэтому такие ссылки не работали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать нужно так, как описано в документации - с плюсом. Браузеры бывают разные, браузерные движки разные, версии разные (старые, новые), плюс к полю могут быть применены некие фильтры либо какой-то JS-фреймворк может быть задействован, и в любом случае следование стандартам позволит тебе оградить себя от глупых недоразумений и трудноуловимых багов в дальнейшем.